# Networked Time Machine backup does not grow after switching backup disk to a larger one

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

My Time Machine backup on a Time Capsule (.sparsebundle) has reached the size of the disk it was stored and started cleaning up older backups after each backup session.

I have switched the disk to the larger one, but the backup no longer grows: after each backup session Time Machine cleans up old backups and total .sparsebundle size remains constant.

How to nudge Time Machine to notice that the backup disk is larger and it can keep more backups?

sparsebundle has not yet reached its maximum size (from `hdiutil info`):

```
Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
 min     cur     max
3807016888  11719963728 34359738368
```

(1.7TB / 5.5TB / 16TB)

Comment: The sparsebundle probably has a fixed or maximum size. You will have to change its properties with the diskutility in command line.

Comment: @n1000 Does not seem to be a problem with maximum size (see the updated question).